# Find command get file or directory

Tags: files, find, directory

I am trying to write a find command that finds both files and directories, the issue is that I get only files or an error depending on certain variables in the command.

This command outputs nothing at all:

```
find '/mnt/downloads/cache/' -depth -mindepth 1 \( -type f ! -exec fuser -s {} \; \) -o \( -type d -empty \) -print
```

This is because the two filters are not encapsulated in ( ). Why are double quotes needed?

This command outputs files only but not directories:

```
find '/mnt/downloads/cache/' -depth -mindepth 1 \( \( -type f ! -exec fuser -s {} \; \) -o \( -type d -empty \) \) -print
```

Extra set of brackets encapsulating the two arguments is the only difference.

The last variation of the command results in an error:

```
find '/mnt/downloads/cache/' -depth -mindepth 1 \( \( -type f ! -exec fuser -s {} \; \) -o \( -type d -empty {} \) \) -print

find: paths must precede expression: {}
```

Why does adding a second set of {} after diretory test results in this error?

Fixed command:

```
find "/mnt/downloads/cache" -depth -mindepth 1 \( \
-type f \! -exec fuser -s '{}' \; -o \
-type d \! -empty \) \
-print
```

Comment: Umm - doesn't it output twice because you are using both `-print` and `-exec echo {}` ? Why would you put the extra `{}` after `-empty`? AFAIK it doesn't take an argument, so that's why `{}` is being parsed as a misplaced path.

Comment: @steeldriver You are right about print / echo, I though I had removed it. Edited question to remove that part. So you are saying that the {} is an argument of exec only and type d / f doesn't need {}? If so why am I still not getting directories in the output? Feel free to add it as an answer as I can't accept a comment no matter how correct it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the implied *and* (`-a`) has higher precedence than the `-o`, the right hand side of the `-o` in the first expression is taken as one unit with regard to the *or* operation, i.e. this:

```
\( -type f ! -exec fuser -s {} \; \) -o \( -type d -empty \) -print
```

acts the same as this:

```
\( -type f ! -exec fuser -s {} \; \) -o \( -type d -empty -print \)
```

So for files, it runs `fuser`, and for directories it prints their names.

---

The second:

```
\( \( -type f ! -exec fuser -s {} \; \) -o \( -type d -empty \) \) -print
```

has explicit parenthesis, but you don't need the inner ones, this is equal:

```
\( -type f ! -exec fuser -s {} \;  -o  -type d -empty  \) -print
```

And it should print all empty directories and files for which `fuser` returns a falsy value (!= 0, inverted by the `!`).

---

In the third you have  `... -empty {} ...`, where the `{}` is taken as path name, and the error message tells what the issue is.

Comment: Ahh, what I wanted is ! -empty, I missed the not operator...